# Shortcode to get featured image of specific id post

Tags: functions, shortcode

So I'm trying to create a shortcode to get specific id and its featured image to display it in a specific page. I want to use shortcode to make it easier for the user to add any post in this page.

I've tried a simple code which works but only display title, I'm not sure how I can get the featured image instead of the title.

```
function post_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '',
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( isset( $id ) ) {
        return '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</a>';
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'test', 'post_shortcode' );
```

Comment: See [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Answer (score 1):

Using your example I've updated it to return instead of the title the image.

```
function post_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '',
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( isset( $id ) ) {
        return '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'thumbnail' ) . '</a>';
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'test', 'post_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Cool thanks, I want to remove a href as I want each thumbnail to go to different external links. But when I remove it I get unidentified thumbnail.

Comment: Didn't understood really well what you were trying to say, can you elaborate a bit more?